# How can i know what parameter i am sending?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i implemented a function to permit the parameters

```
def send_params
        params.require(:article).permit(:color, :skin, :cover)
      end
```

right now i want to know what parameter i am sending

for example only i am sending the color in this case:

```
#<ActionController::Parameters {"color"=>""} permitted: true>
```

with this conditional, is validating the value of color, does not matter the value, i am interesting the parameter that i am sending

```
 if params_search[:color].present?
```

Comment: Do you want to know what params are sent to BE?

Comment: @LeeDrum yes :color, :skin, or :cover, i am sending since postman, i would like to know what parameters is being sending

Comment: The question is pretty bizarre - if you're sending a request with Postman you should probally know what it is that you're sending. Are you actually asking how to test if a parameter is sent by the client in your controller?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gem pry`

- gem link: https://github.com/pry/pry
- code example will be:

```
def create 
  binding.pry
  # some logic using `send_params`
end
```

- The steps:

1. add `binding.pry` to `action` of `controller`
2. go to `Postman` and send data
3. go to console where running `rails s`
4. call `params` or `send_params`

Comment: please without gems

Comment: @tunosist could you use rails log? `Rails.logger.info(send_params)`

Answer (score 0):

In the logs you can see what params you are sending. For example if you post to `/articles` and you send all three params you would see it like this:

```
Started POST "/articles" for [IP_ADDRESS] at [DATE_TIME_STAMP]
Processing by ArticlesController#create as [html/json/something_else]
Parameters: {"article"=>"{"color"=>"blue", "skin"=>"skin value", "cover"=>"some cover"}}
```

If you only send the color than the logs would look like this:

```
Started POST "/articles" for [IP_ADDRESS] at [DATE_TIME_STAMP]
Processing by ArticlesController#create as [html/json/something_else]
Parameters: {"article"=>"{"color"=>"blue"}}
```

You can access the params object with: `params[:article]` and if you want to access the color: `params[:article][:color]`